# Better compression for h265 transparent mov video

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, h265

I created a 3d animation that I converted from an image sequence (211 pngs @ 30fps) using this command:

```bash
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -vf "scale=460:-1" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuva420p output.webm
```

Since Safari doesn't support transparent WebM videos, I need to create an h265 mov file. I found these parameters but it creates a ~1mb video for a 3s loop.

```bash
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -c:v hevc_videotoolbox -allow_sw 1 -vf "scale=460:-1, premultiply=inplace=1" -vtag hvc1 -alpha_quality 0.85 -q:v 80 output.mov
```

Is there a way to compress the loop to get closer to the webm video filesize (360kb)?